# Linq to sql and sql injection attacks

Tags: linq

Does using linq-to-sql prevent and protect from sql injection attacks?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL it generates uses "parameterized queries", they are not vulnerable to traditional sql injection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx

> Q. How is LINQ to SQL protected from
>   SQL-injection attacks?
>
> A. SQL injection has been a
>   significant risk for traditional SQL
>   queries formed by concatenating user
>   input. LINQ to SQL avoids such
>   injection by using SqlParameter in
>   queries. User input is turned into
>   parameter values. This approach
>   prevents malicious commands from being
>   used from customer inpu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because arguments are passed as parameters to the SQL it generates.

Answer (score 0):

Partially?? YES , Fully?? NO . Its the way how you are designing your application , if you use LINQ only with compiled queries then you are safe but if you intend to build adhoc queires based on varying criterias, then you are susceptible to SQL Injection specially when you execute adhoc queires on your datacontext.

Comment: @frenchie: that you built by concatenating sql strings in your code like string query = "select * from Employee Where empID = " + txtEmpID.text ;